# Motors on autonomous driven vehicle free spin in opposite direction they are turning while powered

Tags: motor, dc, failure

I work as a project manager for an Automated Guided Vehicle manufacturer located in Germany. I have a small team of technicians that assist me in installations and maintenance support in the US.

Currently we have a vehicle that is causing an issue with the motors. We can give this vehicle a drive command, which it follows. When we apply force in the opposite direction, the unit will roll in that direction. As soon as we let go of the AGV it continues to drive forward again. We have ruled out any input failures from the controls, since it releases the brake and actually drives forward or reverse when told to.

Does anyone know if this sounds like a mechanical failure inside both motors? What could cause a DC motor to exhibit these conditions?

Comment: What do the manufacturers say? What did they say when you (know doubt) spoke to them first before asking blindly on a site like this? What do your technicians say? Can you be clear what the problem is precisely and unambiguously?

Comment: Ground vehicle? Are you sure this isn't an unknown feature? It really sounds like it might be a feature everyone forgot about. A person being pushed backwards does the same thing because all the alternatives are worse. If I built a rover I would make it do the same thing rather than risk busting the gear train or burning out the motors, so long as it is tuned to still be able to go up and down inclines.

Comment: Tow function, I guess. It has to work even if the vehicle is completely unattended. Otherwise it could not be towed backwards from a fire hydrant etc.

Comment: Can you show some pictures, please?

Comment: What type of motors, and how much information can you offer about the drivers?

Answer (score 0):

> We can give this vehicle a drive command, which it follows. When we
>   apply force in the opposite direction, the unit will roll in that
>   direction. As soon as we let go of the AGV it continues to drive
>   forward again.

Did you remember to remove the "Drive" command? You don't say that, only that you pushed it in the opposite direction and when you ceased, it resumed its previous motion. If the Drive command is still valid, that sounds as though it is doing exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: I feel like the OP expects the robot to continuously force driving forward even when pushed backwards (presumably not on the collision sensors), which would obviously be bad for the robot.

Comment: @JRaef The drive command isn't removed since we want this unit to continue in the same direction. The topic that it is rolling in reverse direction should be nearly impossible to do with the motors already turning in the opposite direction. I was hoping I could get someones personal experience with DC motors, of larger scale. These are not small toy motors, they are 24v 400w micro motors that produce to a lot of torque. See link for motor specifics.
https://exportpagescdn.net/v2/pdfs/product/5065b038-b0f0-11e6-90ca-3a6bba99afcb/wheel-hub-drives-swissdrive-400-t-by-micro-motor-ag.pdf

Comment: @Andy aka      I'm not sure why this matters, but yes I have spoken to them. A programmer reached out to me for support on the problem. The unit is not in our possession currently, it is at a customer in Detroit. I would not post this question if he had already received an answer. To be specific the unit is owned by a union run company. So there is a lot of red tape surrounding who can work on it. We are just trying to point them in the right direction, by either exchanging both motors or a control issue. (Although I've never seen 2 motors fail at one time)

Comment: Sorry, I interpreted that the "problem" was that the motors continued on in the original direction, you seem to be saying that the problem is that you can push it in the opposite direction? That's simply a function of the amount of force involved. I can (and have) pushed my 4,000lb car up a small hill when I ran out of gas once, the point being that humans can exert a lot of force against an object with wheels. Assuming 4 motors, 24n-M each, 96n-M of torque is not as much as you might think, especially with leverage (angle of your body against the AGV).